# WiX DLL component refuses to install

Tags: wix, installation

I am using Wix to install an application.  The trick here is that the application is being installed on top of another, third party application. 
I am installing both using a bootstrapper.

The application I am installing on top of has a DLL that we have customized in OUR application, so I need to overlay the original DLL with ours.

What is happening is that our application installer seems to be refusing to install the DLL.  The log shows this in the InstallValidate step:

Component: DotEditPanels.dll; Installed: Absent;   Request: Local;   Action: Null

I have tried all sorts of things to make this happen.  I started with using A  tag in the Component to delete the original DLL, followed by a  to install it.

The component is getting skipped, as you see above.

I then went to using a Custom Action to delete the original DLL, which works fine, with just the  in the Component.  Same thing.

Trying a few more things, the Component currently looks like this:

```html
<Component Id="DotEditPanels.dll" Guid="*" NeverOverwrite="no" SharedDllRefCount="yes">
  <File Id="filF8E7A8CEDC214A73A82277F1BA3B677F" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\DotEditPanels-8.1-FP2\bin\$(var.Configuration)\DotEditPanels.dll" />
</Component>
```

All I need is for this new DLL to get laid down, and I can't seem to make the installer do it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just one note:  Our customized DLL is using OUR product version in its assembly info, "4.0.0.<build number>", whereas the original file has ITS version number in it "8.1.0.7" - I think the problem is due to our file having a lower version number, but I don't know how to get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File overwrite rules are based on file versions, so if your file version is less than that of the installed file, that's the obvious explanation. This rule is the basis of patches, hot fixes, service packs and so on, so if your version control is doing it's job that existing version should be newer than yours. The assumption is also that Dlls like that are compatible with older apps that may already be installed.

Anyway, you mention an assembly, so if it's managed code then you can set AssemblyFileVersion to a version that will overwrite the existing Dll. Otherwise it defaults to the assembly version. If you need to keep the assembly version the same because clients are bound to it they will still be ok, then use file version to denote later versions and overwrite older versions.

Answer (score -1):

I figured as much.

So, I actually "cheated".  I added the DLL as a Binary object, then used a custom action to delete the original DLL and read the new DLL from the Binary object in the installer database and write it to the proper place.

Yes, I know it's probably not "kosher", but it is getting the job done for my purposes.